# How do you implement and configure ZuulFilter of type route when using spring-cloud-starter-zuul?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

How do you implement and configure ZuulFilter of type "route" when using `spring-cloud-starter-zuul`? The idea is that instead of forwarding to another service, I would like a certain ZuulFilter to handle the request and not forward to another service.

Comment: I guess you've got the application doing the zuul stuff, implemented as a service. Why not implement a standard web filter here?

Comment: You want a simple zuul filter just for forwarding requests to another url ?

Comment: @XtremeBiker,  I thought of web filter too. But what's the purpose of Zuul filter with type "route"?

Comment: @Padi, I actually want the opposite.

Comment: @ely have you looked at the spring-cloud zuul docs to see if there's some way to configure it using configuration files? If not, just DIY.

Comment: You can implement PreZuulFilter && PostZuulFilter which will handle the request on get/post methods. For ex. try to add a new class @Component
public class PreZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter and in run() method you can handle the request

Comment: To get the request : final RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way to do this is to setup a route that forwards to a local spring mvc controller, rather than trying to have a zuul filter deal with it.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    second:
      path: /second/**
      url: forward:/second
```

And then somewhere in the zuul app is a controller

```
@RestController
public class Second {
    @RequestMapping("/second/{value}") /* etc... */
}
```

You could do it in zuul filters, but it very unwieldy. This way, you take advantage of the ease of spring MVC.

Comment: I was searching for a mechanism to forward a request to the local controller for a very long time and I stumbled upon this answer. Not sure if this answers the asked question but it solves my question. Kudos for answering.